# How can I discretize four long and complex functions with Mathematica?

Tags: functions, discretization

I am looking for a procedure with Mathematica where one can discretize  a function in a specific interval to a set of multidimensional vectors. In this way, we can possibly ease the calculation time required to work with these long functions.
All I could find on Mathematica is https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscretizeRegion.html
but this is not relevant.

To get an idea of the complexity of these functions, the functions are shown here

https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/2abadd04-3d65-4f29-bd8c-e847f1607ef4

Thanks

Comment: You could use 'Table' to sample the function at regular intervals. Something like 'Table[{x,d[x]},{x,-1,1,inc}]' . The issue would be to choose a value for inc that is small enough for what you need. This is related to the highest frequency of interest in your time history.  Am I along the correct lines? After sampling then you could use 'Partition' to seperete into subintervals.

Comment: I believe you're looking for the term "interpolation" instead of "discretization", perhaps?

Comment: @Hugh, exactly. This is what I was looking for... The aim is to find a minima between the discretized functions there, and another set of related discretized functions. Then use these minima to solve the system of equations that give a Gaussian function with 4 unknowns.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do it:

```
fi = FunctionInterpolation[g[x], {x, -3, 3}]
Plot[fi[x], {x, -3, 3}]
```